# Docker swarm internal ip address

Tags: docker, networking, docker-swarm

I'm experiencing an odd issue with Swarm and internal ip resolutions. 
I have a manager node where I configured a proxy to other containers running on worker nodes.
All containers have been attached on the same custom overlay network.

Basically, it seems that Swarm is not able to resolve the name with the correct IP:

```
PING geoserver (10.0.0.8): 56 data bytes
64 bytes from 10.0.0.8: icmp_seq=0 ttl=64 time=0.672 ms
64 bytes from 10.0.0.8: icmp_seq=1 ttl=64 time=0.237 ms
```

If I check the overlay network inside the container I got a different ip:

```
"id": {
                "Name": "geoserver.1.6okorb8kie28lpv5lxu135y74",
                "EndpointID": "id",
                "MacAddress": "02:42:0a:00:00:09",
                "IPv4Address": "10.0.0.9/24",

            }
```

So, why I see two different IPs across nodes in the same cluster?
And which is the node responds to 10.0.0.8 ?

Here's the compose file:

```
version: '3'
services:
  proxy:
    image: pk/rh_proxy:base
    container_name: rh_proxy
    ports:
      - "80:80"
    deploy:
      placement:
        constraints:
          - node.hostname == rh02
  [....]
  geoserver:
    image: kartoza/geoserver
    container_name: rh_geoserver
    deploy:
      placement:
        constraints:
          - node.hostname == ms02
    networks:
      default:
        external:
          name: "rh_overlay"
```

and

```
ID                            HOSTNAME            STATUS              AVAILABILITY        MANAGER STATUS
la6ucl7xwnbc0hihn9fw2ugb1 *   rh02                Ready               Active              Leader
n88rw8sharboecp3t6ej0fljk     db-01-bis           Ready               Active              
xa32bamrwyk2egfxdbu6xmn8j     ms02                Ready               Active
```

Cheers, 
FB

Comment: Care to share your compose file? That way we could help you better

Comment: Are you facing an issue or its just that you are seeing two different IPs and you want to know why?

Comment: Added details to origin querstio. BTW, i'm facing the issue.